# Get Only one website details in admin section Product Grid page

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, websites, product-grid

I am working on magento extension, i check this code is written in grid.php file for product listing.

```
Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->toOptionHash()
```

When print_r this then it is given me array of website like

```
Array ( [1] => Website1 [14] => Website2 )
```

but i want this function should written only one one website. In which manner i change this line so that it give me single website details.

Example: $website_id = 14;

Then i place this variable into this line then it gives me details of that variable website only like,

```
Array ( [14] => Website2 )
```

Function line of module is ,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get detail of website by id

Mage::app()->getWebsite($website_id);

Comment: I cant use this line of code for achieve me website details. Kindly check my question.

Comment: The code you mentioned is from Grid.php and is meant to add column to grid to show the website of the product and use for filtration. therefore it must return array of websites. To view products on only once website, you can simply use website filter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
    $websiteIds = array(14);
    $this->addColumn('websites',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Websites'),
            'width' => '100px',
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'websites',
            'type'      => 'options',
            'options'   => Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->addIdFilter($websiteIds)->toOptionHash(),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get it like that

```
  $website_id = 14; //fetch the website data 
    $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite($website_id); 
    echo $website->getId(); 
echo $website->getDefaultGroup(); 
echo $website->getDefaultGroup()->getDefaultStore(); 
echo $website->getDefaultGroup()->getDefaultStore()->getId();
```

Comment: It is used in grid.php file. And return array format with its key and value like update question.

Comment: You want to add store of it? Too

Comment: No actually i want to change above line of code, check in attached question image. So that it can provides me only one website details in array.

Comment: Above line of code is present in grid.php of product. It present in "app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php"

Comment: You are working with core files?  What you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes this is core line but i use locally from my module, i want some change in this line Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->toOptionHash() and it provides single website array details only w.r.t to variable value.

Comment: Use this Mage::getModel('core/website')->load (14)->toOptionHash()

Comment: It provides.. Invalid method Mage_Core_Model_Website::toOptionHash.

Comment: Use toOptionArray

Comment: use this Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',14)->toOptionHash(),